# Can i add <textarea> inside Tinymce editor?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I integrated `Tinymce` in `Rails 4 application`. Now, i added content in Tinymce from admin and display it front side and works fine.

But as per requirements, I have to `add <textarea> <input> tags into Tinymce editor` and display it front side in HTML format.

I tried lots but not get any idea. Any one have trick or idea in it.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the purpose of Tinymce to actually input text trough a textarea? I mean.. is kind of odd to try to save a "textarea" trough a "textarea" ...

Comment: ..you could use the "add code" button in Tinymce then add your code as `<textarea rows="6" cols="85" placeholder="something here."></textarea>` . this should work, but any additional "save" on the tinymce, while "add code" isn't active will likelly broke your code...